# react-native-camera (android): takePictureAsync() throws error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

After calling takePictureAsync() from react-native-camera, i'm getting this error:

```
{
  "framesToPop": 1,
  "nativeStackAndroid": [],
  "userInfo": null,
  "message": "Preview is paused - resume it before taking a picture.",
  "code": "E_TAKE_PICTURE_FAILED",
  "line": 2131,
  "column": 45,
  "sourceURL": "http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"
}
```

So I tried using resumePreview() method before calling takePictureAsync() and now I'm getting a different error message:

```
{
  "framesToPop": 1,
  "nativeStackAndroid": [],
  "userInfo": null,
  "message": "takePicture failed",
  "code": "E_TAKE_PICTURE_FAILED",
  "line": 2131,
  "column": 45,
  "sourceURL": "http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"
}
```

My component and usage i identical to that of https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera

```
    <RNCamera
      ref={ref => {
        this.camera = ref;
      }}
      style={styles.preview}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
      flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
      androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
        title: 'Permission to use camera',
        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      }}
      androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
        title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
        message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      }}
      onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
        console.log(barcodes);
      }}
    />




takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      try {
        this.camera.resumePreview();
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        console.log(data.uri);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      }
    }
  };
```

versions:

```
"react-native": "0.61.2",
"react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
```

Works fine on iOS.
Is this an issue with the library or my implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use component as FaCC (Function as Child Components)! This way worked for me.

```
const PendingView = () => (
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}
  >
    <Text>Waiting</Text>
  </View>
);

class ExampleApp extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
        >
          {({ camera, status, recordAudioPermissionStatus }) => {
            if (status !== 'READY') return <PendingView />;
            return (
              <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.takePicture(camera)} style={styles.capture}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        </RNCamera>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture = async function(camera) {
    const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
    const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
    //  eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(data.uri);
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an issue with the library or my implementation?

It appears to be a problem with the example code.  I noticed the same thing and my solution is similar to [FredVieira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340956/fredvieira) but doesn't use FaCC. It appears that the camera will not resume on Android unless the RNCamera component has children.  So if you change the example from

```
<RNCamera ... /> 
<View ...>
          <TouchableOpacity ...>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

to

```
<RNCamera ...>
<View ...>
          <TouchableOpacity ...>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
</RNCamera>
```

it should work.  So you can use a function or a component, just as long as the RNCamera has a child.